# creating my own shorttags using regex?

Tags: regex, tags

Let's say I have the following short-tag regex:

```
\[BANNER{([0-9]*)}{(site1|site2)}{([A-Z]*)}\]
```

basically, I have a CMS which should take this shorttag, ex:

```
[BANNER{23}{site1}{HELLO}]
```

and print out something like this:

```
<a href='http://site1.com?par1=23&par2=HELLO'>SOME TEXT</a>
```

Now, it works great whenever I input all those 3 parameters, but how can I make them *optional*?
so that it'll accept any of the following options:

```
[BANNER]
[BANNER{23}]
[BANNER{23}{site1}]
```

and will output something default, I thought about making a capture group over each of the curly brackets {} - but I guess I got the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, you may start from the

```
\[BANNER({([0-9]*)})?({(site1|site2)})?({([A-Z]*)})?\]
```

Comment: That regex creates too many groups, you might want to exclude some groups (?:)

Comment: @SeRPRo : You are right of course. I wrote as simply as possible solution but it was not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This one should work:

```
/\[BANNER{([0-9]*)}(?:{(site1|site2)})?(?:{([A-Z]*)})?\]/
```

See the result [here](http://xrg.es/?2694854902)